# sbt native-packager RPM install directory issue

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

I have tried to modify the install dir of my RPM. This seems to work, however my RPM now is missing the `init.d` start script. When I look in `target/universal/tmp/bin`, I don't see systemv-init.

Below is my snippet code from my `build.sbt` that show how I am overriding the install directory. I have custom start script in `src/templates` directory for my scala fat jar app. When I remove the below install directory override, the RPM packages fine and install ok in `/usr/share`. Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

```
linuxPackageMappings in Rpm <<= (linuxPackageMappings) map { mappings =>
  for(LinuxPackageMapping(filesAndNames, meta, zipped) <- mappings) yield {
    val newFilesAndNames = for {
      (file, installPath) <- filesAndNames
    } yield file -> installPath.replaceFirst("/usr/share", "/opt")
    LinuxPackageMapping(newFilesAndNames, meta, zipped)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by removing the above code and just adding one liner to my `build.sbt`:

```
defaultLinuxInstallLocation:= "/opt"
```